# JS + SVG circles overlapping

Tags: javascript, svg, nodes, appendchild, removechild

I am writing a survey app in Javascript. This is the idea: there are some questions and answers in a .js file and then I show them dynamically to the screen by clicking a button. The answers are put in circles, that are also added dynamically as nodes and appended to the svg. But now I have a problem: when I click on next, the old circles dont dissapear and overlapp with the new ones.

How can I make the circles dissapear?

Thanks!

```
let optionNr = questionsAndAnswers.allQuestions[l].answers.length;
let unit = (1920 - offSet * 2) / (optionNr * 2);


i = 0;

while (i < optionNr) {
   var svgNode = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];  
   let newCircle = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'circle');      
   i++;



              let centerX = offSet + (unit * (i* 2  - 1));                                            
              newCircle.setAttribute("class","circle");                                              
              newCircle.setAttribute("cx",centerX);                                                  
              newCircle.setAttribute("cy","850");                                                    
              newCircle.setAttribute("r","150");                                                     
              newCircle.style.stroke = "black";                                                      
              newCircle.style.strokeWidth = "2px";                                                   
              newCircle.style.opacity = circleOpacity[i-1];                                          
              newCircle.style.fill = circleColour[i-1];
              svgNode.appendChild(newCircle);                                                        


              let answerID = "answers" + i;
              let newAnswer = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'text');        
              newAnswer.setAttribute("class", "answer");                                             
              newAnswer.setAttribute("id", answerID);                                                
              newAnswer.setAttribute("x",centerX);                                                   
              newAnswer.setAttribute("y","860");                                                     
              newAnswer.setAttribute("text-anchor","middle");                                        
              newAnswer.setAttribute("font-size","46");                                              
              newAnswer.setAttribute("fill","cyan");                                                
              svgNode.appendChild(newAnswer);                                                        
              document.getElementById(answerID).textContent = questionsAndAnswers.allQuestions[l].answers[answerNumber];


}
```

Comment: If you are using JQuery try this `$("#svgid").empty();` in that way you clean your svg before you draw the new circle. let me know if that resolve your problem

Comment: The thing is that everything there is on screen are svg nodes and by removing everything there will be nothing left. I tried using                                           $('.class').remove(); But I want to show the elements and then when I click on next to remove them. Edit: I dont know how to format that as code

Comment: I FIXED IT! I used $('.class').remove(); but I had to add it somewhere else. Yeeey